# Scroll to top in another screen after second click - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, persistence

I have an app where I want to add scroll to top in the **HomePage** if user clicks on the home button and I have two screens where **1. Index page** (where i navigate to different screen using bottomNavigation widget) and **2. Home Page** which is the first index that is navigated to when a user visit the app

**Index Page**

```
List<Widget> selectedScreen;
PageController _pageController;
int _selectedIndex;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _selectedIndex = 0;

    selectedScreen = [
      HomePage(),
      BooksScreen(),
      NotificationScreen(),
    ];

    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _selectedIndex);
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

///...

body: PageView(
     controller: _pageController,
     children: selectedScreen,
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
       BottomNavigationBarItem(              //This is the home button which navigates to HomePage()
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),  //This is the home button which navigates to HomePage()
            label: "",                       //This is the home button which navigates to HomePage()
          ),
       //item 2
       //item 3
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,        
),
       
///...

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
      
    });
  }
```

**Home Page**

```
///...
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<HomePage> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(children: [
             ///...
```

But i don't know how to go about this because if am in the second screen and i click on the home button i want the scroll to top to do nothing because the home screen has a persistent scroll which means that it stays the way it is when you leave the page and come back but if the user clicks on the home button while still on the **HomePage** then i want the home page to scroll to top just like facebook, youtube, quora and other apps.

Please how do i do this and if you did not understand you can ask me to explain more

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your method:

```
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  if(index == _selectedIndex && index == 1){
      controller.animateTo(0, Duration());
    }
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
      
    });
  }
```

And use the ScrollController (controller) in your ListView